# Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\sitename', even though it's in db_owner role

Tags: sql-server, webforms

I'm setting up a legacy ASP.net Web Forms site developed by a previous developer on a new server, using a SQL Server database.

Usually I grant db_owner permissions to `'IIS APPPOOL\example.com'` to get the database connection working on other websites.

However, I've done that for this one and I'm still getting an error as if I hadn't done it:

> Cannot open database "TheDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\example.com'.

I've tried this on a couple of test domains, same on both.

All the trouble shooting steps I've found on Google tell me to grant access to this user, but I've already done that. What could be causing this / how can I fix it or even trouble shoot it?

I have got it working on my local machine but only in IISExpress.

Local machine is latest Windows 10, server is Windows Server 2012.

**Update**

Connection string (the same connection string just with different database names works well on all my other sites):

```
   <add name="SQLServer" connectionString="Server=.;Database=TheDatabase;Trusted_Connection=true;"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Have you looked at the logs in the SQL Server? They will give you a more specific authentication error reason.

Comment: Can you post your connection string from the web config for clarity?

Comment: The log has this error: 2020-01-15 11:08:18.88 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38. - looked online but just says it's a login issue same as main error message.

Answer (score 0):

The moral of this story - TRIPLE check the database name, there was a typo in it. Correcting the database name fixed the issue.